# Confluent kafka-connect-s3 same source multiple sinks

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using [Confluent's Kafka s3 connect](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3) for copying data from apache Kafka to AWS S3. For our use case, we want to copy data from Kafka to multiple S3 buckets.

One S3 bucket having partitioning strategy like this -

```
s3.bucket.name=kafka-s3-test1
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
timestamp.extractor=Wallclock
locale=US
timezone=UTC
partition.duration.ms=3600000
path.format='ds'=YYYY-MM-dd/'hour'=HH
```

And the other S3 bucket having partitioning strategy like this -

```
s3.bucket.name=kafka-s3-test2
partitioner.class=com.custom.CustomFieldPartitioner
partition.field.name= eventPlatform, eventType, eventDate
```

One obvious way is to maintain 2 different kafka-connect clusters for each of the sinks. 
I am wondering if there is a way to send same data to 2 different sinks(like this use case)?
And if not, how can I extend this library to implement the same?

Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one cluster. The bucket is a configurable property (s3.bucket.name)

If you have different AWS S3 credentials for accessing the buckets, then you'll need separate **Java processes** (which could result in separate clusters, but not required)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the property file snippet to include bucket name as well. Both the buckets are in the same AWS account. So thats not the problem. But how can i use 2 different s3-sink.property files in the same java process?

Comment: `connect-standalone.sh worker.properties s3-sink1.properties s3-sink2.properties`... Or you **should** run `connect-disributed` because its fault tolerant

Comment: thanks. I tried using like this "connect-standalone.sh worker.properties s3-sink1.properties s3-sink2.properties" but events are getting pushed either to sink1 or sink2 and not both. I can see events that are present in sink1 but not in sink2. So not sure if this is the correct solution for this use case.

Comment: It assure you that it is. Please verify your topics are actively produced to

Comment: ok.. let me generate some test data and check again. On the other note, if i use 2 sinks like mentioned above, does Kafka connect maintains transaction internally? What will happen if Kafka connect crashes after writing data to one of the sinks? Since in this case same Kafka offset will be used by both sinks, how will failures be handled?

Comment: Kafka Connect does not have transactions support, last I checked, but S3 Connect does maintain exactly once processing. https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once/

Comment: yes..I have seen that but i was confused if that will still hold true if i run kafka connect with multiple s3 sinks. anyways, thanks for clarifying. On the other note, do you know if somebody has already wrote integration test for kafka-connect-s3?

Comment: Yes, the semantics are isloated per consumer thread. The code logic is open source and uses MockS3Client